# Create filter of an attibute and other of a date range

Tags: symfony, filter, twig

I've a list of items of my Entity. I want to filter it by an attribute as do SonataAdminBundle or other Admin Generator.

For example, if I have an attribute "color" then in my view should have a select field with the types of color and when the user choose one of them my view should only show the list of items filtered by "color"

How do I do it?

**Edit:**

I have almost solved first filter creating a form and in the controller action get the attribute using the request. Then I used findBy to filter the query.

Now is time of date range filter and merge it with the filter above. I want to filter my list of items by two o three filters.

How do I get from the controller to return only items that belong to a date range?

What is the sentence DQL to use three filters which are optional? I can filter out for none, one or all filters.

Comment: Done! I knew nothing about it

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the solution: [Doctrine Filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html)

This is what I use if I only want to get a subset of related entities. I think the Documentation is straight forward.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for.